# How to change description text size on MPAndroidChart PieChart"?

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I have the following settings on [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library by implement a PieChart, but I need to set description text size.

```
PieData data = new PieData(valsPieX, set1);
    data.setValueTextSize(20f);
    if(usePercentSymbol)
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());

    pieChart.setData(data);
    pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false);
    *pieChart.setDescription(Description);*
    pieChart.highlightValues(null);
    pieChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Change your question to read "on MPAndroidChart PieChart" and you will get more hits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pieChart.getDescription().setText("Description Text goes here"); //the text which will be displayed. 

pieChart.getDescription().setTextSize(16f); //sets the size of the label text in density pixels min = 6f, max = 24f, default is 10f, font size will be in dp

pieChart.getDescription().setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_red_dark)); //the color of the font 


pieChart.getDescription().setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT); //Sets the text alignment of the description text. Default RIGHT
```

**pieChart**: is the your chart object, it can be `PieChart`, `BarChart`, `LineChart` or any other chart type.

**Description**: is the object which is returned by `getDescription()` from chart.

Answer (score 2):

`pieChart.getDescription().setTextSize(16f);`

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.